# A way to import only certain Blogger posts to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I would like to import a client's posts from Blogger to Wordpress

I have searched for blog posts, plugins, and scripts that do what I need, and have not been able to find what I am looking for. A question from 2016 asks the same thing, but the solution offered is to upload all posts and delete the ones you don't want. I would like to try to avoid having to delete 600+ posts manually. Has anyone found a solution for this issue?

Edit:

Requirements from client:

She has compiled a spreadsheet in Google Docs of posts that she would like to keep that has the Original Blogger Title, Original Blogger Post Date, What will be the new category, and what will be the new tags. This is the only way I know which posts she would like to bring over. So far I have been using process of elimination and deleting posts one-by-one.

Things I've tried:

The default Blogger importer froze. So I've tried to use [Blogger Importer Extended](https://wordpress.org/plugins/blogger-importer-extended/), but I'm not sure what's extended about it, because it does the same as the default importer, indiscriminately importing everything.

Update:

Reporting back. I cannot get a Blogger XML export to open in Excel to be converted to .csv. I tried then exporting the Wordpress posts as XML to convert to CSV also. However, both times I tried this with different methods, I got the same error from Excel:

[image: Excel Error Message regarding XML formatting]

So I now need to know how to convert whichever XML format that Blogger/Wordpress use to .csv so it can be compared/contrasted to the list I have received from the client. Will report back later.

Update2:

Was able to convert to csv using the online service proposed below, however the output is seemingly useless, unless I'm missing something. The output appears as below:

[image]

Comment: What is your criteria for deleting the posts? Date based? We need more information on what you're actually trying to do. Edit your question with all your requirements.

Comment: I have edited my original question per your request. She has compiled a spreadsheet in Google Docs of posts that has the Original Blogger Title, Original Blogger Post Date, What will be the new category, and what will be the new tags. This is the only way I know which posts she would like to bring over

Comment: Perfect. Unfortunately, there will be some manual work that you will need to do or have the client do. One way to potentially do it is: export the existing Blogger posts. Convert that to a CSV file. Take the new google sheet (client provided) and compare the two spreadsheets based on post title to create a third spreadsheet with all the data from the first sheet where the post titles match. You should end up with only the posts the client wants. Then use WP All Import plugin to import the data via CSV.

Comment: I've edited my original post with an update, if you care to take a look. I'm struggling now with converting to .csv. Once I clear that hurdle I think we can automate this process.

Comment: Try this online service to convert: http://www.convertcsv.com/xml-to-csv.htm

Comment: Awesome, it worked, but the output is just four lines in excel that don't really seem to be useful. Do you know how I would go about comparing it with the list the client has provided? I have updated my original post with a screenshot in excel.

Comment: Without seeing the original XML, not sure what is happening. As for comparing, that's something for an Excel/Google Sheets expert.

Comment: The XML is standard XML with opening/closing tags and the CSS is included as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the default WP Importer have issues when you import XML filtered to a particular author. For this type of task, [CSV Import/Export plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/) will be useful. Also, you must install the [WP export add-on](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-exporter/) for export option and use the filter options like "Export data by specific Author" or "Specific Period" checked as in this image https://ps.w.org/wp-ultimate-exporter/trunk/screenshot-2.png?rev=2134132. Now you can export the CSV of blog posts filtered for particular Author or Date range. You can use this CSV now to import again.